# How to disable type.js effect on mobile

Tags: jquery, type.js

Is there any way to disable **`type.js`** effect on mobile and tablet devices?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to detect if your page is loaded by a mobile or tablet to decide to load/instantiate or not the script. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/2159528)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette will have a try. Is there any specific default property in type.js?

Comment: Their documentation is quite minimal... What I suggest is to check on what type of device you are before instantiating type.js on an element. This will work for sure.

Comment: yeah you are right, their document is very minimal. Let me try the way you said.